# Why can't I index into an ExpandoObject?

Tags: c#, dynamic, expandoobject

Something caught me by surprise when looking into C# dynamics today (I've never used them much, but lately I've been experimenting with the Nancy web framework). I found that I couldn't do this:

```
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();

expando.name = "John";

Console.WriteLine(expando["name"]);
```

The last line throws an exception:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type
>   'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject'

I understand the error message, but I don't understand why this is happening. I have looked at the documentation for ExpandoObject and it explicitly implements `IDictionary<,>` and thus has a `this.[index]` method ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd630221(v=vs.110).aspx)). Why can't I call it?

Of course, there's nothing to stop me from downcasting the `ExpandoObject` to a dictionary manually and then indexing into it, but that kind of defies the point; it also doesn't explain how the Expando was able to hide the method of one of its interfaces.

What's going on here?

Comment: Explicit interface implementations can only be accessed if the object is cast to that interface, it is not something particular to ExpanoObject.

Comment: Relevant source code: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Actions/ExpandoObject.cs,552

Answer (score 82, accepted):

> how the Expando was able to hide the method of one of its interfaces.

Because as you correctly found out in the documentation, the [indexer is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx) an [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx). From [Explicit Interface Implementation Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(v=vs.71).aspx):

> A class that implements an interface can explicitly implement a member of that interface. When a member is explicitly implemented, it cannot be accessed through a class instance, but only through an instance of the interface.

This means you'll have to cast the reference to the interface to access it:

```
((IDictionary<String, Object>)expando)["name"]
```

Comment: Thanks @CodeCaster. I knew about explicit interface implementation, but I thought it was just for implementing two members with the same name; I'd never seen it used merely to hide a member before. Do you know why they've done this with ExpandoObject?

Comment: @Richiban one can only guess, but see [Marc Gravell's answer on a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280495/why-to-use-explicit-interface-implementation-to-invoke-a-protected-method): _"to keep the core public API clean"_.

Comment: This seems to defeat the purpose of even using an ExpandoObject.  May as well just declare it as a Dictionary.

Comment: @Triynko they created ExpandoObject for the ASP.NET MVC viewbag, it's one of the most useless types anywhere else.

Comment: @Triynko I'm surprised that your comment has this many likes. ExpandoObject in this context can be used both as `dynamic` and `Dictionary` you can assign a field dynamically `exp.MyField = 3` and read it as a dictionary value `((IDictionary<String, Object>)exp)["MyField"]` or vice versa. There is a situation in my project which can only be solved using ExpandoObjects.

Answer (score 4):

Use this factory class to create ExpandoObjects! Then use HasProperty("prop name") or GetValue("prop name")

```
void Main()
{
    dynamic _obj = ExpandoObjectFactory.Create();
    if (_obj.HasProperty("Foo") == false)
    {
        _obj.Foo = "Foo";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(_obj); // Foo;
    object bar = _obj.GetValue("Bar");
    Console.WriteLine(bar); // null
}

public static class ExpandoObjectFactory
{
    public static ExpandoObject Create()
    {
        dynamic expandoObject = new ExpandoObject();
        expandoObject.HasProperty = new Func<string, bool>((string name) => ((IDictionary<string, object>)expandoObject).ContainsKey(name));
        expandoObject.GetValue = new Func<string, object>(delegate (string name)
        {
            ((IDictionary<string, object>)expandoObject).TryGetValue(name, out object value);
            return value;
        });
        return expandoObject;
    }
}
```