# C# Code for Moq's Setup and it's Return in regards to mocking a dynamic property

Tags: c#, dynamic, moq, xunit, expandoobject

Here is info about our technical development environment :

- .NET Core 3.1
- PostgreSQL 14.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit
- EntityFramework.Functions Version=1.5.0
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design Version=5.0.17
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools Version=5.0.17
- Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL Version=5.0.10

In my application, I have a Generic Target Class, and it's corresponding Wrapper class and Wrapper interface.

```
public class TargetWrapper<T> : ITargetWrapper<T>
{
    private Target<T> _target;
   
    public TargetWrapper()
    {
        _target = new Target<T>();
    }

    protected internal TargetWrapper(Target<T> target)
    {
        _target = target;
    }

    public T Data 
    { 
        get { return _target.Data; } 
        set { _target.Data = value; } 
    }
}
```

I have the a Business Logic class called `JohnDoeClass` has the following code that uses the TargetWrapper which sets the generic type to a dynamic:

```
public class JohnDoeClass 
{
    public EmailRecord MaryDoeMethod(ITargetWrapper<dynamic> targetWrapper)
    {
        var dataset = targetWrapper.Data.someDynamicMetaDataEntity;

        return new BlahEntity()
        {
            Id = dataset ["id"],
            FaxId = dataset["fax_id"],
            FaxNumber = dataset["fax_number"],
            FaxLocation  = dataset["fax_location"],
            Subject = dataset["subject"]
        };
    } 
}
```

However, when it comes to Unit Mock Testing using the Moq Framework, I do Not know how to code the Moq Setup and it's Return in the following code:

```
public class JohnDoeClassTests
{    
    [Fact]
    public void MaryDoeMethodTest_Valid()
    {
        Mock<ITargetWrapper<dynamic>> targetWrapperMock = new Mock<ITargetWrapper<dynamic>>();
    
        dynamic returnedInfo = new ExpandoObject();
        returnedInfo.Id  = 3;
        returnedInfo.fax_id = 7;
        returnedInfo.fax_number = “416-949-9393”;
        returnedInfo.fax_location =”348 Rover Drive, New York, NY, USA”;
        returnedInfo.Subject = “Tax Rebate info 2023”;        

        graphQLResponseWrapperMock.Setup(r => r.Data …What toplace as code here in order Setup someDynamicMetaDataEntity dynamic property to return > something ?                                                                                  
            .Returns(What do I place here in order to return the returnedInfo dynamic object );
                                          
    } 
 }
```

How can I write code for Moq's Setup and its return in regards to mocking the dynamic property in question?

Answer (score 3):

First of all your `MaryDoeMethod` will not work. It will throw `RuntimeBinderException`:

> Cannot apply indexing with to an expression of type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject'

[In order to fix the indexing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778554/why-cant-i-index-into-an-expandoobject) you need to explicitly state that the `ExpandoObject` should be treated as `IDictionary<string, object>`

```
IDictionary<string, object> dataset = targetWrapper.Data.someDynamicMetaDataEntity;
```

---

Now, back to your test. I would suggest to use `anonymous type` to construct the expected return object and then use [some helper method](https://sebnilsson.com/blog/convert-c-anonymous-or-any-types-into-dynamic-expandoobject/) to convert that to `dynamic`.

The helper method

```
public ExpandoObject ToExpandoObject(object obj)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();

    foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj.GetType()))
    {
        expando.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(obj));
    }

    return (ExpandoObject)expando;
}
```

This will not work for nested data structures. Either you need to extend it to work with them or create the outer `ExpandoObject` by hand. For the sake of simplicity let me show you the later one:

```
var expected = new
{
    someDynamicMetaDataEntity = new
    {
        id = 3,
        fax_id = 7,
        fax_number = "416 - 949 - 9393",
        fax_location = "348 Rover Drive, New York, NY, USA",
        subject = "Tax Rebate info 2023",
    }
};

IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();
expando.Add(nameof(expected.someDynamicMetaDataEntity), ToExpandoObject(expected.someDynamicMetaDataEntity));
```

With that in our hand the mock setup is as simple as this

```
targetWrapperMock.Setup(w => w.Data).Returns(expando);
```

---

Here you can find a working example on dotnet fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vWC5VA

Comment: love respect thank you. you saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the the time dynamic is underpinned by a value, and just allows dynamic access. Given you're accessing your data as a key/value structure, you can mock a dictionary

```cs
Mock<ITargetWrapper<dynamic>> targetWrapperMock = new Mock<ITargetWrapper<dynamic>>();

Dictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
Dictionary<string, object> metadata = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    ["Id"] = 3;
    ...
}

data.Add("someDynamicMetaDataEntity", metadata);

targetWrapperMock
    .Setup(r => r.Data)
    .Returns(data);
```